# Export specific processes with Powershell Windows 2008

Tags: powershell, memory, process, export, taskmanager

I am pretty fresh with Powershell. Scripting and coding of any kind is actually not what I went to college for if you will. But here I am.

A little background: I am trying to balance my WebSphere nodes and ensure that memory usage is being properly distributed. To do this I want to export all of the Java processes into an excel sheet.

```
Get-Process Java | Select-Object processName, WS
```

This is what I started with. Now my script looks more like this:

```
gwmi win32_process -filter "name='chrome.exe'" |  Select-Object name,processId,@{Name='WorkingSet (KB)';Expression={ Get-Process Chrome ($_.WorkingSet/1KB)}},commandLine  | format-table -autosize
```

You can try this one yourself assuming you have Chrome running and you'll see that the WorkingSet (KB) column is blank. I don't really know how to fix this and it's the only piece missing. I'm really curious to know what i've done wrong and why.

Comment: Remove get-process chrome from your custom select expression

Comment: The only thing this accomplished is putting a '0' value.. not the value of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem. For some reason $_.WorkingSet did not work. I had to make one change.

```
 Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%chrome.exe'"|select ProcessName,@{Name='WorkingSet (KB)';Expression={($_.WS/1KB)}},ProcessId,CommandLine|ft -AutoSize
```